# How do I programmatically generate an array of all permutations of a string pattern?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to compare a string grabbed from a URL, with a list of cities in a MySQL DB, using PHP

```
SELECT 'city' WHERE 'city' IN (" . $citynameArray . ") LIMIT 1;
```

`$citynameArray` is to be list of all possible permutations of `$cityname`, where `$cityname` may be up to 5 strings separated by hyphens, BUT 'city' may use either spaces OR hyphens to separate each string.

So 'city' may look like any of these:

- string
- string string
- string string string
- string string string string
- string string string string string
- string-string
- string-string-string
- string-string-string-string
- string-string-string-string-string
- string string-string
- string-string string
- string-string string string
- string string-string-string
- string string string-string
- string string string-string
- string-string-string string
- string-string string-string
- string-string-string string
- string-string string string string
- string-string-string string string
- string-string-string-string string

... and so on, to a maximum of 5 separated strings

In the vast majority of cases however, 'city' is either:

- string
- string string
- string-string

or, less common:

- string-string string
- string string-string

My question then, how do I generate the array? And, by using `'LIMIT 1'`, will the query stop looping through the array as soon as a result is found?

I appreciate any insights,

regards,

GJ

Comment: You really should normalize your input data and database as such a query easily can be an overkill for your database.

Comment: Could we see some examples of data that actually appears in the database and in the URL? For one thing, when you write (e.g.) "string string-string" it isn't clear whether there's any order that matters. For another, we can't see the format of the data in the city column and (as Fge says) there may be a better way of structuring the data.

Comment: Either normalize your data, as @Fge suggests, or use some flavor of full-text search. Your search should either be exact (normalized) or fuzzy ("Google-like search"), not brute force.

Comment: Can you at least give a valid SQL statement?

Comment: @Fge is right indeed, though @deceze's FULLTEXT solution could work (use boolean mode & `+` / required) as both spaces & hyphens are seen as word boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

I had hoped for elegance, but this will have to do.

CASE 1 represents 90% of use-cases, and the overhead is negligable.

Percentage of use-cases depreciates to CASE 5 which applies to 1 out of 2000 cases. I analyzed the actual patterns for CASE 4, and the patterns did not have to be exhaustive.

```
    // FIRST, CREATE AN ARRAY OF $LocaleURL PATTERNS, TAKING INTO ACCOUNT THE VARIABLE USE OF HYPHENS

    $urlCityArray=explode("-",$LocaleURL);
    $countSegs = (count($urlCityArray)); // how many array elements

    if ($countSegs == 1) {
        $urlCityQuery = $urlCityArray[0];
    } 
    else if ($countSegs == 2) {

        $urlCityQuery  = $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . "-" . $urlCityArray[1];

        // city1 city2, city1-city2
    }
    else if ($countSegs == 3) {

        $urlCityQuery  = $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . " " . $urlCityArray[2] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . "-" . $urlCityArray[1] . " " . $urlCityArray[2] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . "-" . $urlCityArray[2] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . "-" . $urlCityArray[1] . "-" . $urlCityArray[2];

        // city1 city2 city3, city1-city2 city3, city1 city2-city3, city1-city2-city3
    }
    else if ($countSegs == 4) {

        $urlCityQuery  = $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . " " . $urlCityArray[2] . " " . $urlCityArray[3] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . "-" . $urlCityArray[2] . " " . $urlCityArray[3] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . "-" . $urlCityArray[1] . "-" . $urlCityArray[2] . "-" . $urlCityArray[3] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . " " . $urlCityArray[2] . "-" . $urlCityArray[3];

        // city1 city2 city3 city4, city1 city2-city3 city4, city1-city2-city3-city4, city1 city2 city3-city4
    }
    else if ($countSegs == 5) {

        $urlCityQuery  = $urlCityArray[0] . " " . $urlCityArray[1] . " " . $urlCityArray[2] . " " . $urlCityArray[3] . " " . $urlCityArray[4] . "', '";
        $urlCityQuery .= $urlCityArray[0] . "-" . $urlCityArray[1] . "-" . $urlCityArray[2] . "-" . $urlCityArray[3] . "-" . $urlCityArray[4];

        // Notre-dame-de-lile-perrot
    }

    SELECT 'city' FROM Cities WHERE 'city' IN (" . $urlCityQuery . ") LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: To format lines as code, indent them four spaces. The "101\n010" button will do this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more formatting tips.